# Strange phpMyAdmin Issue: Inline Editing Just Stopped Working Along with Dropdown Select

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, phpmyadmin

I have the strangest issue I have probably ever seen in coding.  I use phpMyAdmin (in this case version 3.5.2.2).  For 6 months everything has worked as I have always experienced with phpMyAdmin.  But just in the last week, certain features stopped working, like inline editing and auto submit after selecting a dropdown.

There have been no changes in the code.

There have been no changes in the environment.

There have been no changes in the browser.

It is so weird.  But just like that certain functions (which I imagine are JavaScript functions) stopped working.

I tried updating to version 4.1.13, but that brought a whole other weird issue in that it will load the page, but it is just a white screen.  Sure you'd assume it is a PHP or environment error.  My initial thought too.  But when I view the source, it actually renders a full set of HTML, but displays none of it.

While the 4.1.13 was a weird issue, my main objective is just to get inline editing and dropdown features restored.

I do get three weird console errors but all my searching has produced nothing:

- Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
- Uncaught ReferenceError: PMA_getImage is not defined
- event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.

Any suggestions on where to look?  I have spent hours trying myself and finally turning to you guys.

Comment: have you uninstalled and then reinstalled?

Comment: something along the lines of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19135666/unreadible-characters-in-phpmyadmin-sources)? Try to focus on the illegal character as the others issues will be triggered by that one.

Comment: Yes agreed with Ohgodwhy. Take a backup of db, project etc. Then reinstall it again. Although i prefer to use XAMPP.

Comment: I have uninstalled and reinstalled to no avail.  I have also upgraded and that didn't help.  I have also taken a working copy on another server and replaced it on this server and still the same issue.

Comment: @Tim Vermaelen - I saw that when troubleshooting myself.  I guess I couldn't figure out where the error was.  As it seemed to be about downloading a new copy, but this was a working situation and then just broke with no intervention.

Comment: I'm having this issue too. Looking around, it seems that the way phpMyAdmin includes files with relative paths is a real nightmare. Non-best practices to say the least.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured this out.  3 Steps.  I guess I should mention that I was trying to do phpMyAdmin over SSL.

**Step 1 - Config**
ADD: $cfg['ForceSSL'] = true

**Step 2 - /js/get_image.js.php**
In the very last line there is a blank link.  Mine is around line 137.  Comment it out with //

**Step 3 - /js/functions.js**
Search for 'jsversioncheck' - mine was around line 100 in a mimified line of code
Put that function on it's own line and then comment it out.  You will lose the ability to have an automated message about most recent phpMyAdmin versions.  But frankly, I'll take the SSL over that message any day.

Ultimately I think the issue JavaScript features failing (like inline edit and dropdown select) is that JavaScript itself was failing after bugs that were unrelated to the feature.  These bugs were related to doing phpMyAdmin over SSL - which suprises me significantly that more people don't do and that this issue seems to be relatively unreported.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: nice workaround though, digging inside the minified js and all! I'll +1 you for that ^^
Although some other things come to mind. I remember something about http 1.1 protocol settings in IE (not sure which browser you're using). Also downloading phpMyAdmin you chose the proper version for your OS, right? Basic questions but still, it's an odd issue for a fresh install. I'll give you that.

Comment: Thanks.  I use Chrome normally.  But that was the weird thing about this error is that I opened it up on two separate IEs that had never even visited the site (no cache issue) and they didn't work either.

Comment: Also, Tim, your comment helped.  While I am not sure the 1.1 protocol was the issue here, you posting that link caused me to read it a whole lot closer than before and it is what led me down the path that solved the problem.  So thank you.

Comment: If you still want to check it out. In `Internet Options` > `advanced` > `Use HTTP 1.1` and make sure it's checked. Else I'm sure you're happy you got it to work ^^